# Setting up mail server that can handle multiple users for side project

Tags: email, ssl-certificate

I want to set up a mail server that can handle multiple users.
Basically, the end application will assign each user an address, say
example1@testdomain.com. The users can send emails to this address, and they will be processed and integrated into the application.

I have looked into doing this with postfix on ec2, but my problem is that I will be receiving much of my email through gmail, which requires ssl on both sides. Does this require that I get a certificate for my domain?

Is there any cheaper alternative (given that this is just a side project).

I know of services like mailgun but I want to be able to write the processing code to handle incoming mail on the mail server itself, not via api.

Comment: "but my problem is that I will be receiving much of my email through gmail, which requires ssl on both sides"  <--- where did you get that information? They require no such thing.

Comment: If a gmail user attempts to send to my ec2 server, it may be blocked because its not a tls connection correct?

Comment: That is incorrect.

Comment: So I just need to set up postfix on an ec2 server, hook it to my domain and I should be good to go?

Comment: In theory, yes. Mail admin sucks, though, and if you're new to this, you can expect to spend a lot of your time troubleshooting.

Comment: Cool thank you, for the project I just need the ability to receive emails at an address and add aliases, so hopefully it won't be a problem unless google doesn't send for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22510/discussion-between-meursault-and-eeaa).